# How can i stop cube from rolling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i got a runner game and cube is my player, the problem is i can't stop cube from rolling. The ground is slippery(friction = 0) but it is still rolling. When i freeze rotation of y axis it seems like lagging so it doesn't work either. Please help me. There is my movement code

I changed values of mass and drag but it didn't help.

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float forwardForce = 2000f;
public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
public float acceleration;
public PlayerMovement movement;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    forwardForce += Time.deltaTime * acceleration;

    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

There are no error messages.

Comment: Freeze the rotation (x, y and z) on the RigidBody component in the inspecter.

Comment: In that case, cube seems like lagging because it is trying to roll so movement doesn't seem smooth.

Comment: Is the Camera a child of the cube or are you settings its position and rotation using  script?

Comment: i am using script, it follows the cube.

Comment: Thats where your issue is, make the Camera a child of the cube and remove the Cameras script, it will move with the cube.

Comment: OR if you are doing something special with the Camera and need the script do the Camrea's update in `LateUpdate` so it is called after the Cube has finished for the frame.

Comment: `public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;
    }`

Comment: this is camera's code and same issue continues :(

Comment: Do you have a pattern on the "track" the cube moves along? I think it may be an optical illusion as both those methods provide Camera tracking without jitter.

Comment: Nope i don't have any pattern. I got a prefab "tile" that 30 cm height and 15 cm width and it clones itself to make the road endless.

Comment: How are you positioning the `tile` prefab, I am now wondering if it is slightly off and the cube is catching the edges where two tiles join and there is a slight gap.

Answer (score 0):

you could try and replace Time.deltaTime with Time.fixedDeltaTime since it's in FixedUpdate.

Comment: That didn't work either. I freezed all rotations and now when the cube tries to flip it is like fps dropping for a sec. I was checking the fps while this was happening and it seemed fine.

Comment: Hmm it's hard to guess what could be wrong with your code since we can only see a small portion of it. I tried your code on a local project and from the data I have and I didn't get your behavior. I can only guess that you must have some other code or setting that is the source of the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after trying to help you in the comments I have written a small demo of what you are trying to achieve so you can use it to try and find where you went wrong before and how I would go about doing what you are trying to do.

**Cube Controls**

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
    public float acceleration = 1;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        forwardForce += Time.deltaTime * acceleration;

        //Using the in-built methods uses the keys you were but also the arrow keys
        float inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        //Check there is input
        if (Mathf.Abs(inputX) > float.Epsilon)
        {
            //set which force direction to use by comparing the inputX value
            float force = inputX > 0 ? sidewaysForce : -sidewaysForce;
            rb.AddForce(force * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

    }
}
```

There are a couple of changes there but they are commented to explain.

**Camera Tracking**

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraTracking : MonoBehaviour
{
#pragma warning disable 0649
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _cube;
#pragma warning restore 0649

    private Vector3 offset;

    void Awake()
    {
        offset = _cube.transform.position + transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        transform.position = _cube.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

It uses the initial offset between the cube and Camera that is setup before starting the pressing play.

**Tip** *I recommend not using this but making the camera a child of the cube as this is something that you are calcualting each frame which you don't need too!*

**Path Generator**

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PathGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
#pragma warning disable 0649
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _path1;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _path2;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _cube;
#pragma warning restore 0649

    private float _cubeRepositionZDistance;

    private float _pathPositionX;
    private float _pathPositionY;

    //Distance center of path should be behind the cube;
    private float _resetDistanceFromCube = 25f;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // You could hard code this but this way you can change the length of each path segment and it will be updated here automatically.
        _cubeRepositionZDistance += _path1.transform.localScale.z / 2;
        _cubeRepositionZDistance += _path2.transform.localScale.z / 2;

        _pathPositionX = _path1.transform.position.x;
        _pathPositionY = _path1.transform.position.y;

        // Position path2 relative to path1.transform.position
        _path2.transform.position = new Vector3(_pathPositionX, _pathPositionY, _path1.transform.position.z + _cubeRepositionZDistance);

        StartCoroutine(PathRepositioner());
    }

    private IEnumerator PathRepositioner()
    {
        //Can change bool to something like !GameOver
        while (true)
        {
            if (_path1.transform.position.z < _cube.transform.position.z - _resetDistanceFromCube)
            {
                _path1.transform.position = new Vector3(_pathPositionX, _pathPositionY, _path2.transform.position.z + _cubeRepositionZDistance);
            }
            if (_path2.transform.position.z < _cube.transform.position.z - _resetDistanceFromCube) 
            {
                _path2.transform.position = new Vector3(_pathPositionX, _pathPositionY, _path1.transform.position.z + _cubeRepositionZDistance);
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Doing it this way you are reusing the same 2 path segements and not creating clones all the time, you can change it to use 3 or more if needed.

**Scene Setup**

Position the cube and then position the path1 segement under the Cube.

Assign all required GameObjects to the scripts in the inspector.

***Press Play!***

**Sidenote:** It is recommended to move the path segements not the Cube(Player) when doing an endless runner like this but as you are new to this I suggest reading up on that when you get a chance.